# How to create a link to a html file using the Meteor local server?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

Currently, I have an html file which has a basic layout of a login page which has an option for new users to sign up if they're not a member.

I have the following line inside of my html :

```
<a href="register.html">Join Us!</a>
```

What I want to have happen is load up a new HTML page which will be a modal (using twitter bootstrap) that will ask the user to input the correct data to create a login/pass combination.

But this isn't working. It keeps doing the following (doesn't do anything) :

```
http://localhost:3000/register.html
```

I'm a little confused whether my HTML is wrong or MeteorJS requires some sort of specific way to do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a relative url: Example: register.html only
If your file is into the same project, you don't need to put him an url absolute.

Comment: The file is in the same folder, hence, I'm using the relative path. Not sure exactly, what you're suggesting since I'm already using relative path

Comment: Did you already load all the files required from bootstrap page? I mean, your question is try to load your register.html file into a window like a jquery ui or boostrap window popup? Because in this case, you don't need any file, the only that you need is paste the HTML code into the window of bootstrap. See this example: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons

Comment: Yeah, I literally just copied that from the bootstrap page just to test it out and it didn't work. And then I also attempted just creating like a basic hello world html to see if that works, and that didn't work either :( not sure what's going on man

Comment: Don't worry, man. If you are having problems, use de cdn scripts And CSS that Bootstrap provides yiu in the section of getting started.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `register.html` file in your project's `/public` directory and you will be able to access it via `/register.html`. However that page will run outside your Meteor app and won't have any Meteor functionality per se.

The `/public` folder maps to `/` and is normally used for images and other client-side assets. It's common to map `/public/images` to `/images` for example.